# How do you check that a dictionary is in an array even in the worng order in python?

Tags: python

Lets say you have :

```
 winning_numbers = [{345}, {238}, {321} ]

 players_numbers = {435}
```

I want to return True that players_numbers is in the the array even if its not in the right order. How can I tackle doing this?

Comment: That's a set. And it's a set with a single number. Rethink your data handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your winning numbers into a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
>>> winning_numbers = [ {3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 8}, {3, 2, 1} ]
>>> players_numbers = {4, 3, 5}
>>> players_numbers in winning_numbers
True
```

Answer (score 0):

*sets* are of the form

```
{value1... valueX}
```

a *dictionary* is actually

```
{key1:value1... keyX:valueX}
```

As for your question, you could simply use the **in** keyword:

```
if players_numbers in winning_numbers:
    print "you have a winner!"
```